# What is the correct SPF record for an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with it's domain resolved to Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spf

I'm running an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Route 53 is used to resolve the domain to the EB environment. When emails are sent from the environment only some recipients receive the emails, with Gmail receiving them but flagged "Gmail couldn't specify that [the domain] actually sent this message". I assume that the problem is with the SPF record but I have been unsuccessful in the SPF record settings I tested. Any ideas on the correct SPF settings for this scenario? -Thanks!

Comment: This isn't programming related - I'd try [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.  But ultimately you should use any of the online SPF check sites to validate your SPF/DKIM records.  Or you should use [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) and then you don't have to worry as much about it.  The reality is that a good portion of the internet will block a new IP until it is trusted.

Comment: What email platform are you using? Your provider should tell you what SPF/DKIM records to set...